# How to correctly modify Taxonomy Term selection Plugin

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, plugins

I want some slight modifications of `Drupal\taxonomy\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\TermSelection::getReferenceableEntities()`, for example to not use `-` to indicate term hierarchy. How can that be achieved?

I tried to extend that class in a custom module like that:

```
/**
 * Provides specific access control for the taxonomy_term entity type.
 *
 * @EntityReferenceSelection(
 *   id = "default:custom_taxonomy_term",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom Taxonomy Term selection"),
 *   entity_types = {"taxonomy_term"},
 *   group = "custom",
 *   weight = 2
 * )
 */
class CustomTermSelection extends TermSelection {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getReferenceableEntities($match = NULL, $match_operator = 'CONTAINS', $limit = 0) {
    // Customization will be here...
  }
}
```

The plugin seems to be detected, it appears while debugging `$selection_plugins` in `Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem::fieldSettingsForm()`, but it won't appear as reference method on editing the term reference field.

What else do I need to modify to get it work?

Comment: I think you might be looking for this answer here, where they are overriding a core service: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220759/57

Comment: Thank you Kevin, the linked question helped me a lot, especially the accepted answer there. If I could I would give the bounty to your comment :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation in the sample code of my question was wrong. With the help of the first comment to this issue I was able to solve the problem (see [accepted answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220521/10316) there). Although this question is a bit different it might be marked as duplicate to [How to display more than 10 items in link widget autocomplete?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220517).

Anyway I want to leave the custom plugin including the annotation:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Vocabulary;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Plugin\EntityReferenceSelection\TermSelection;

/**
 * Provides specific access control for the taxonomy_term entity type.
 *
 * @EntityReferenceSelection(
 *   id = "custom:taxonomy_term",
 *   label = @Translation("Custom Taxonomy Term selection"),
 *   base_plugin_label = @Translation("Custom Taxonomy Term selection"),
 *   entity_types = {"taxonomy_term"},
 *   group = "custom",
 *   weight = 2
 * )
 */
class CustomTermSelection extends TermSelection {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getReferenceableEntities($match = NULL, $match_operator = 'CONTAINS', $limit = 0) {
    if ($match || $limit) {
      return parent::getReferenceableEntities($match, $match_operator, $limit);
    }

    $options = [];

    $bundles = $this->entityManager->getBundleInfo('taxonomy_term');
    $bundle_names = $this->getConfiguration()['target_bundles'] ?: array_keys($bundles);

    foreach ($bundle_names as $bundle) {
      if ($vocabulary = Vocabulary::load($bundle)) {
        if ($terms = $this->entityManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadTree($vocabulary->id(), 0, NULL, TRUE)) {
          foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $options[$vocabulary->id()][$term->id()] = Html::escape($this->entityManager->getTranslationFromContext($term)->label());
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return $options;
  }

}
```

One thing I want to point out, which was not part of the above linked answer is the `base_plugin_label = @Translation("Custom Taxonomy Term selection")` (solution found on [d.o. issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access/issues/2869072#comment-12036303)). Without that I got the following notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: base_plugin_label in Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem->fieldSettingsForm() (line 336 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldType/EntityReferenceItem.php).

Comment: I am following your way and annotation to define the plugin. But still I can not get the option for reference method. Is there any suggestion from you to save me from this?

Comment: Is it part of your "custom" module, enabled and caches rebuilt?

Comment: Yes, enabled and caches rebuilt. I suppose to be able to see my custom selection as a option when I configure the reference method for taxonomy-term-reference field. Right? But I can not.

Comment: However, If I manually change the field.field.page.field_pdct_cate.yml file. And do drush cim -y. Then my custom selection plugin is put into effect. It just does not reflect and shows up as option in the UI. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new custom plugin which extends class of target Core plugin.

File: modules/custom/src/Plugin/EntityReferenceSelection/CustomSelection.php

After this you can navigate to field settings and select your method.

Comment: I already created my custom plugin as code in question shows. I had problems to code the correct annotation, that's why it didn't work. With the help of the comment from Kevin I was able to solve that. But anyway, thank you for taking the time to help me.